# Passing Null Value when loading an async map

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm trying to pass this map as a value for the next page route, but the value in **jsonResult** inside MaterialApp goes as a null.

Debugging, it is possible to see that the map contains information about the models. However, in the MaterialApp no, it only appears as a null:

```
  JjModel jmodel = JjModel();
  dynamic jsonResult;

  loadJson() async {
    Map<String, dynamic> mapInicial = jmodel.informacoesIniciais();
    final Directory _appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final Directory _appDocDirFolder =
        Directory('${_appDocDir.path}/fileSettings');

    File jsonFile = File('${_appDocDirFolder.path}/Preferences.json');

    if (await jsonFile.exists()) {
      String data = jsonFile.readAsStringSync();
      jsonResult = json.decode(data);
    } else {
      final Directory _appDocDirNewFolder =
          await _appDocDirFolder.create(recursive: true);
      File jsonFile = File('${_appDocDirNewFolder.path}/Preferences.json');
      jsonResult = mapInicial;
    }
    return jsonResult;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    loadJson();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Menu de Serviços',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: androidTheme(),
      home: ServiceList(jsonResult: jsonResult),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You marked `loadJson` as `async` so it completes *after* `MaterialApp` creation. Wrap `MaterialApp` with `FutureBuilder`, refactor `loadJson` to return value and set it as `future` prop. Then use `snapshot.data`as input for `ServiceList`.

P.S. It is recommended to read more about asyncronicy. Read this for start https://www.woolha.com/articles/dart-event-loop-microtask-event-queue